# Using radio buttons to set item's state with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, radio-button

I currently have a table of `categories` that I iterate and display as a table, where every row has a group of radio buttons that can set the state of a category:

```
<tr v-for="cat in categoryList">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" v-bind:name="'cs-' + cat.id" v-bind:id="'cs-neutral-' + cat.id" value="neutral" v-model="cat.state"> Neutral
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" v-bind:name="'cs-' + cat.id" v-bind:id="'cs-good-' + cat.id" value="good" v-model="cat.state"> Good
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" v-bind:name="'cs-' + cat.id" v-bind:id="'cs-bad-' + cat.id" value="bad" v-model="cat.state"> Bad
  </label>
  </div>
</tr>
```

However when displayed neither a correct radio button gets set, neither the `item.state` updates on change. How to fix this?

Comment: Does the `cat.state` property initially exist (in order for Vue to observe it)?

Comment: @DecadeMoon, it does, I have tried printing it on every iteration and it is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you use this.$set to update array, otherwise Vue will not keep track of changes.

[Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZoorbO?editors=1010)

---

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="cat in categoryList">
      <td>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" :name="'cs-' + cat.id" :id="'cs-neutral-' + cat.id" value="neutral" v-model="cat.state"> Neutral
        </label>

        <label>
          <input type="radio" :name="'cs-' + cat.id" :id="'cs-good-' + cat.id" value="good" v-model="cat.state"> Good
        </label>

        <label>
          <input type="radio" :name="'cs-' + cat.id" :id="'cs-bad-' + cat.id" value="bad" v-model="cat.state"> Bad
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    categoryList: [
      { id: 1, state: "neutral" },
      { id: 2, state: "neutral" },
      { id: 3, state: "neutral" },
      { id: 4, state: "neutral" },
    ]
  }
})
```